# Why do 01, 02, ... 07 parse as integers in the python interpreter but 08 and 09 throw a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, syntax

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.10

$ uname -a
Darwin Carters-MacBook-Pro-2.local 18.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.0.0: Wed Aug 22 20:13:40 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4903.201.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I was trying to do something like this today in the python interpreter

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 07, 26) - datetime.datetime.today()
```

and this worked fine, but when I went to

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 08, 26) - datetime.datetime.today()
```

it throws a "SyntaxError: invalid token"

Then I tried this

```
>>> 01
1
>>> 02
2
>>> 03
3
>>> 04
4
>>> 05
5
>>> 06
6
>>> 07
7
>>> 08
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    08
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

what's going on?

Comment: doh! That should be obvious! This would appear to be a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

This is because in python 2 leading zeros denotes that the number is an octal number so as in octal we don't have 8 it goves this error.

Note: Python3 doesn't allow leading zeros